# Order by date in SQL Server not showing properly

Tags: sql-server, date

I want to view my table as `order by date`.

I have written this command

```
select * 
from companydetails 
order by date desc
```

Output:

> 4/1/2013 30-11-16 
>   30-11-16 
>   29-11-16 28-11-16 27-09-16 27-01-2014
>   26-11-16 26-07-14 24-02-15 23-09-15 23-03-15 21-10-15 21-01-16
>   20-08-15 18-11-15 18-03-15 17-08-16 17-04-14 16-09-14 15-02-14
>   15-02-14 15-02-14 15-02-14 15-02-14 15-02-14 15-02-14 14-11-14
>   14-08-14 12-02-14 12-01-2013 11-03-16 09-10-15 08-12-15 06-01-16
>   04-01-2013 03-01-14 02-10-15 02-09-14 02-09-14 01-12-15 01-12-14
>   01-12-14 01-10-15 01-10-15 01-10-14 01-09-15 01-09-15 01-09-14
>   01-09-14 01-09-14 01-09-14 01-08-15 01-08-14 01-08-14 01-07-15
>   01-06-15 01-06-15 01-04-2014 01-04-14 01-04-14 01-04-14 01-04-14
>   01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13
>   01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13
>   01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13
>   01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13 01-04-13 01-03-16 01-03-14 01-03-14
>   01-02-16 01-02-15 01-01-15 01-01-15 01-01-14 NULL

This is not what I needed this is only ordering day and I google it on web and found out this

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
     companydetails 
ORDER BY 
   CONVERT(DateTime, date,105)  DESC
```

but this is throwing an error

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

when I choose modify my table, I find out my superior create date as `nvarchar(50)` what do I need to do now?

Comment: I think you should store your dates as `datetime` and not `varchar`.

Comment: i know but my superior use to store the dates in nvarchar and now i am facing the problem for the same

Comment: @InformationHTI : your date format is inconsistent too.

Comment: if i make all the dates like 01-02-14 this, then can i do what i want??

Comment: which version of sql server is this?

Comment: What you can to is to first make your date consistent and then try using `cast`.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your comment, you already realized that your `date` field is at `nvarchar`.

There are several thing you need to concern now:

1. Are there any application / website / reports that read / write this table?

   - If Yes: unless you can control all of the source / else it will be tedious to modify your database.
   - If No: Consider on migrate your `date` field to `DateTime` data type.
2. Do you want to migrate the data type for `date` field?

   - If Yes: Your date format in `date` field is not consistent. You will need to find out where it is, update it to 1 and only 1 format, (yy-MM-dd or yyyy-MM-dd) or whatever it is more comfortable for you. Then after that you can convert this field to `DateTime` datatype.
   - If No: Even if your data is consistent, it will not follow date time order when you arrange, but follow alphabet order, which will give you a wrong order somewhere, sometimes.
     So to use this `CONVERT(DateTime, date,105)  DESC`, you will need to edit your data to 1 same format first. For example, I can see these 2 records are not consistent: `01-06-15` & `01-04-2014`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you change your data in the column and made it consistent as you stated in comment.
Then try this:-

```
SELECT CAST(Column_Name as datetime2(7)) from tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since datatype used to store your datetime is NVARCHAR.
For this, You cast it as DATE or DATETIME.

```
select * from companydetails order by CAST(date as DATE) desc
```

The format of the date used to store is not consistent as per the requirement for the SQL Server.

From Your Output: 
30-11-16 is one format of date. Not in the format of MM-DD-YYYY.

01-04-13 is one more format. Even though this is a valid format now, it takes it as Jan 4th against your intended value (I'm assuming) of April 1st.

The server throws an error at 30-11-16 because it takes it in the format MM-DD-YYYY( But 30 is not a valid month and hence your error.)

So, you need to follow this specific format for date and then use the above query.

Hope this helps.